# Apply CSS on class generated programatically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this module and i need to apply CSS to my div class which i am generating programmatically i don't understand how to achieve that, I have used the inline and constant methods but didn't find any solution that how to apply CSS on remaining tags. Please help because without those CSS styling my component is not any worth.

```js
<script type="text/jsx">
    var styles = {
        width: '140px',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        marginBottom: '12px',
        height: '20px' 
    }
    var color = {
        backgroundColor: '#6cb33e'
    }
    class PasswordStrength extends React.Component {    
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {                        
                type: 'password',
                checked: false,
                meterTitle: 'Invalid',
                meterClass: 'danger',
                meterWidth: 0,
                rules: {
                    isValidLength: false,
                    hasNumber: false,
                    hasLetter: false
                }
            };
        }

        onPasswordChange(e) {
            this.setState({          
                rules: {
                    hasNumber: e.target.value.match(/\d/) ? true : false,
                    hasLetter: e.target.value.match(/[A-z]/) ? true : false,
                    isValidLength: e.target.value.match(/^.{6,}$/) ? true : false
                }
            },function(){
                this.setMeterAttributes(this.state.rules);
            });         
        }

        setMeterAttributes(rules){
            var meterWidth = this.getMeterWidth(rules);
            this.setState({
                meterWidth: meterWidth,
                meterTitle: (100 === meterWidth ? "Strong" : "Medium" && 50 > meterWidth ? "Easy" : "Medium"),
                meterClass: (100 === meterWidth ? "" : "warning" && 50 > meterWidth ? "danger" : "warning")           
            });  
        }


        getMeterWidth (rules) {
            var property_count = 0, valid_property_count = 0, property;
            for (property in rules) {
                if (rules.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    property_count = property_count + 1;
                    if (rules[property]) {
                        valid_property_count = valid_property_count + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (valid_property_count / property_count) * 100;  
        }

        getSingleRuleStatus(status) {       
            if(status){
                return "valid";
            }
        return "invalid";
        }

        render() {      
            return (                            
                <div className="password-strength-widget">
                    <Password type={this.state.type} onChange={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <RulesMeter title={this.state.meterTitle} className={this.state.meterClass} meterWidth={this.state.meterWidth}/>        
                    <RulesList 
                        isValidLength={this.getSingleRuleStatus(this.state.rules.isValidLength)} 
                        hasNumber={this.getSingleRuleStatus(this.state.rules.hasNumber)}
                        hasLetter={this.getSingleRuleStatus(this.state.rules.hasLetter)}
                        />
                </div>           
            )
        }
    }

    class RulesMeter extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                    <div style={styles} className="meter-wrapper">
                       <div className={this.props.className} style={{width: this.props.meterWidth + '%'}}></div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    class RulesList extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <ul>
                    <li className={this.props.hasNumber}>
                        At least one number (0-9)
                    </li>
                    <li className={this.props.hasLetter}>
                        At least one letter (a-z)
                    </li>
                    <li className={this.props.isValidLength}>
                        At least 6 characters
                    </li>   
                </ul>
            )
        }
    }

    class Password extends React.Component {  
        render() {
            return (
                <span>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Create Password</label><br/>               
                    <input
                    id="password" 
                    type={this.props.type} 
                    placeholder="Enter password...."               
                    onChange={this.props.onChange} 
                    /> 
                </span>   
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( <PasswordStrength/>, document.getElementById('app') )
</script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Password Strength Meter</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="app"></div>           
    </div>
```

```css
CSS i need to apply:

.password-strength-widget .meter-wrapper div
        {
            height:20px; 
            background-color: #6cb33e;
        }
        .password-strength-widget .meter-wrapper div.danger 
        {        
            background-color: #d40000;
        }
        .password-strength-widget .meter-wrapper div.warning 
        {        
            background-color: #FFF200;
        }
```

Comment: In React your css propery name should be camelCase.. background-color should be  backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

You can either put this css in a separate .css file and include it with the `<style>` tag, or you can do it inline in your HTML.

Your React code looks ok where you are referencing the classes

Option 1) External CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css">
```

Option 2) Inline styles

```
<style>
  h1 {color:red;}
  p {color:blue;}
</style>
```